# IE redirecting to .application file

Tags: security, internet-explorer, admin-rights

I have a page (page1.html) whose content is simply:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta charset='UTF-8'>
<script language='javascript'>
  var redirecturl = 'http://www.mywebsite.com/file.application?ts=123456';
  function redirect() {
    var anchor = window.location.hash;
    window.self.location = redirecturl + anchor;
  }
</script>
</head>
<body onload=redirect()></body>
</html>
```

This code works fine in various versions of Chrome and FF on various machines. However, this doesn't *always* work in IE. I have a colleague using IE 9 w/o admin rights, for whom this does not work. I also have a virtual machine running IE 11 w/ admin rights for which this also doesn't work.

Confusingly, I am using IE 11 w/ admin rights and this does work, I also have a separate colleague using IE 10 w/o admin rights for whom this does work. So the success rate seems somewhat varied and I can't see anything in each of our settings that should suggest it should work for one and not another.

I should expand slightly, the behaviour is such that it simply doesn't download the file, or even offer the box asking to save the file (for those that aren't working). I've run Fiddler on those two machines, strangely on the machine running IE 9 I can actually see a request made for the redirect URL, whereas the machine running IE 11 doesn't even do that.

Oh, and lastly, if I hit the URL I'm trying to redirect to directly, on any of the machines in any of the browsers, it works fine.

Is there a security measure kicking in somewhere that might be causing this?

Comment: What does "doesn't work" mean? What happens there? Does onload fire?

Comment: By doesn't work I mean it doesn't display a "Would you like to save this file?" dialog. The script appears to work perfectly without error, looking at the console it even tells me that a navigation has occurred. I've since found this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5299076/window-location-doesnt-work-after-an-ajax-request-in-internet-explorer, what's odd is that I'm able to get it working for some versions of IE 11, which that question would suggest I shouldn't work at all post IE 9.